# How do I remove Blutooth Indicator?

Tags: release-loki, wingpanel

Before Loki I used to do- `apt-get remove-indicator-Bluetooth` and it used to work fine but now if I do this whole wing panel get displayed. For my purpose, I don't use Bluetooth at all and I think if I can remove the indicator it would be good. Please let me know if I can remove this icon. Thanks

Comment: I've also tried: `sudo apt-get remove wingpanel-indicator-bluetooth` And as OP had said, after rebooting the system the whole wing panel disappears. Can someone provide a solution to this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To remove the Bluetooth indicator, I believe the package you are looking for is 'wingpanel-indicator-bluetooth' which, once removed, will remove the indicator for you. In terminal, you can:

```
sudo apt-get remove wingpanel-indicator-bluetooth
```

That should do it for you.

Good Luck!!!

Comment: problem is, this will remove entire wing panel!

Comment: I tested the above command in both a Virtual Machine setting as well as in a Live Session booting from USB and in neither instance was the Wingpanel removed.

Comment: https://plus.google.com/+AjEthan       . .. .  no it won't work.